# UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter with identifier headerid - must register a nib or a class for the identifier

Tags: ios, swift

I have a cell in my Xcode project

```
    let head="headerid"
    collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: head)

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let aheader=collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: head, for: indexPath )
    aheader.backgroundColor = .orange
    return aheader
}
```

When I try to run this file it gives me an error
`'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter with identifier headerid - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`
Even though other cells(not `forSupplementaryViewOfKind`) are working in this code